# Checking $\xi$ solves the conformal killing equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, field-theory, conformal-field-theory, vector-fields

**Problem:**

I am trying to prove that, using:

$$\xi^\mu (x) = a^\mu + \omega ^\mu_\nu x^\nu + \sigma x^\mu + b^\mu x^2 -2b_\nu x^\nu x^\mu \tag{1}$$

and

$$\kappa = \sigma -2b_\nu x^\nu \tag{2}$$

prove the *conformal killing equation* to be correct:

$$2\kappa(x) \eta_{\mu\nu}= \partial_\mu \xi _\nu + \partial_\nu \xi_\mu\tag{3}$$

---

**Attempt:**

I started by substituing $\kappa$ and to write the LHS of $(1)$ as:

$$2(\sigma-2b_\nu x^\nu) \eta_{\mu\nu}= 2\sigma\eta_{\mu\nu}-4b_\nu x_\mu \tag{4}$$

To correctly solve the RHS of $(3)$ I lowered the indices on $(1)$ and obtained:

$$\partial_\mu \xi_\nu = \partial_\mu(a_\nu + \omega_\nu ^\mu x_\mu + \sigma x_\nu + b_\nu x^2 -2b^\mu x_\mu x_\nu ) \tag{5}$$

a similar equation to $(5)$ would be obtain for $\partial_\nu \xi_\mu$ .

I think I can ignore the first term of $(5)$ as $a_\nu$ is just a constant and I think I should re-write $b_\nu x^2 $ as $b_\nu x_\mu x^\mu$ but I don't know where to go from here to prove the equation to be correct.

Comment: Might it help to notice that $a,\omega,\sigma,b$ are all constants and $\omega$ is antisymmetric?

Comment: Oh so if $\omega$ is antisymmetric, then $\omega^\mu _\nu = - \omega ^\nu _\mu $ and I will obtain a term like:
$$\omega^\mu _\nu (\partial_\mu x_\mu + \partial_\nu x_\nu )$$

and so:

$$\partial _\mu \xi_\nu + \partial_\nu \xi_\mu =\omega^\mu _\nu (\partial_\mu x_\mu + \partial_\nu x_\nu ) + \sigma(\partial_\mu x_\nu +\partial_\nu x_\mu) + (b_\nu x_\mu + b_\mu x_\nu) - 2(b^\mu  \partial_\nu x_\nu x_\mu -b^\nu \partial_\nu x_\nu x_\mu )$$

Should I put the $\partial x$ factor on the last term of the equation and on the $\omega $ term together? I am not sure where to go from here. Thanks

Comment: I decided to type up an answer because I noticed some tiny mistakes in your expressions. That's why you must have gotten stuck. Hopefully now it's clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From OP's attempt

$$2(\sigma-2b_\nu x^\nu) \eta_{\mu\nu}= 2\sigma\eta_{\mu\nu}-4b_\nu x_\mu \tag{4}$$

and

$$\partial_\mu \xi_\nu = \partial_\mu(a_\nu + \omega_\nu ^\mu x_\mu + \sigma x_\nu + b_\nu x^2 -2b^\mu x_\mu x_\nu ) \tag{5}$$

Referring to a comment in the opriginal post: recall that for (anti)symmetric tensors it makes sense to talk about the permutation of indices at the same height. Namely
$$
\omega_{\mu\nu} = -\omega_{\nu\mu}\,,
$$
saying $\omega^\mu_\nu = - \omega^\nu_\mu$ is imprecise because it is not clear which index should be lowered/raised first.

Anyway, back to the problem. From $(5)$ take a derivative using that all parameters are constant. In order to not mess up, we should call the contracted indices with different names than the external ones, so let me rewrite $(5)$ first as
$$\partial_\mu \xi_\nu = \partial_\mu(a_\nu + \omega_\nu ^\rho x_\rho + \sigma x_\nu + b_\nu x^2 -2b^\rho x_\rho x_\nu ) \tag{5'}$$
Now the derivative reads (use $\partial_\mu x_\nu = \eta_{\mu\nu}$)
$$
\begin{aligned}
\partial_\mu\xi_\nu &= 0 + \omega^\rho_\nu \eta_{\rho\mu} + \sigma \eta_{\mu\nu}+2b_\nu x_\mu- 2 b^\rho \eta_{\rho\mu}x_\nu-2b^\rho x_\rho \eta_{\mu\nu}
\\&=\omega_{\mu\nu} + (\sigma - 2 b\cdot x) \eta_{\mu\nu} + 2(b_\nu x_\mu - b_\mu x_\nu)\,.
\end{aligned}
$$
Now let's take $(4)$, the same mistake of calling contracted indices as external ones appeared, so let me rewrite it as
$$
2(\sigma-2b_\rho x^\rho) \eta_{\mu\nu}= 2(\sigma-2b\cdot x) \eta_{\mu\nu} \tag{4'}
$$
In order to avoid these mistakes, make sure that there are never three indices or more with the same name. If there are, that should be a warning.

Now we are basically done. We computed $\partial_\mu \xi_\nu$, then $\partial_\nu\xi_\mu$ is the same with the indices swapped. The first term ($\omega_{\mu\nu}$) is antisymmetric, so it goes away. The third term is also manifestly antisymmetric so it goes away too. Finally the middle one is symmetric so it gest multiplied by two. All in all
$$
\partial_\mu\xi_\nu + \partial_\nu \xi_\mu = 2 (\sigma - 2 b \cdot x) \eta_{\mu\nu}\,.
$$