# How do I calculate the infinitesimal transformations of a scalar primary field under a general conformal transformation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, conformal-field-theory

I know that a scalar primary field, $\phi(x)$, with weight $\Delta$, transforms undera general conformal transformation as:

$$\delta\phi(x) = -\kappa(x) \Delta\phi(x) -\xi^\mu \partial_\mu\phi(x)  \tag{1}$$

and that:

$\kappa(x) = \sigma -2b\cdot x$

$\xi^\mu (x) = a^\mu + \omega^\mu _\nu x^\nu + \sigma x^\mu + b^\mu x^2-2b \cdot xx^\mu$

---

**Aim:**

I am trying to prove that $$\mathcal{O}_\mu= \phi_1 \partial_\mu \phi_2 - \phi_2 \partial_\mu \phi_1\tag{2}$$ is a primary operator of dimension, $2\Delta+1$ , transforming as a vector , by knowing that $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are scalar operator of dimension $\Delta$ (meaning that I must check if the transformation $\delta_D$ and $\delta_{K_\mu}$ act in the right way).

---

**Attempt:**

Started by calculating $\phi_D \mathcal{O}$:

$$\delta_D (\phi_1 \partial_\mu \phi_2 - \phi_2 \partial_\mu \phi_1)= \delta_D\phi_1 (\partial_\mu \phi_2) - \delta_D\phi_2(\partial_\mu \phi_1)\\ = \delta_D\phi_1 (\partial_\mu \phi_2) + (\partial_\mu \phi_1) \delta_D\phi_2  $$

**But I don't know how to calculate $\delta_D \phi_1$ or $\delta_D \phi_2$. I understand that I must use eq.(1) but I don't understand real meaning of the values that define $\kappa$ and of $\sigma_\mu$.**

**How can I use equation (1) to prove equation (2)?**

*This isn't homework, it is an exercise on a lecturer's notes that I am trying to do once more outside the lectures.*

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/540155/2451

Comment: Just to make sure that this is not an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/): you know that you could prove that $\mathcal{O}_\mu$ is primary much more easily by showing that it's killed by $K_\nu$, right?

Comment: This isn't an XY problem, the problem is the proof  of the dimension of the operator being $2\Delta +1 $.